# Finding property in Object

Tags: javascript

Imagine this scenario:

```
var myObject = {
    "1030":{},
    "1059":{}
}
```

I want to check if `1030` is in that object.
How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```
if(myObject.hasOwnProperty("1030")) {
    // Do code
}
```

It's a bit safer than checking `if(myObject["1030"])`. This will return false, if the value is falsey (`false`, `undefined`, `null`), which may be desirable, but also does not strictly mean it does not exist.